# Local Storage turns wrong or null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to set some value in local storage. So i do this:

```
if (localStorage) {

    var event = localStorage.getItem("Event");

    if (event != "undefined" || event != "null") {
        console.log(event)
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("Event", "Event Name");
        console.log('test');
    }
}
```

I can't save value in local storage for the first time. It's not returns anything in `else` condition. Always returns `null` from exist check condition. Can anybody help?

Comment: Quotes are used to make strings. "undefined" is a string literal and it's only equal to the "undefined" string.

Comment: `x != a || x != b` is always true when a != b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't exist, `null` is returned, not the string `"null"`, so change to:

```
if (event != null) {
    console.log(event)
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("Event", "Event Name");
    console.log('test');
}
```

From the [W3 docs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem):

> The getItem(key) method must return the current value associated with the given key. If the given key does not exist in the list associated with the object then this method must return null.